# How does one do a simple inner container in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's an image of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMbw3.png

I want an outside container with a border and an inner container with a gray background.  Within the inner container are two blocks: text on the left, image on the right (the elements on either side are of no importance - they can be whatever).  Pretty basic stuff.

With the code below, I have my two div's that span 6 columns breaking apart (Here's what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK6bl.png).  What's the best way to fix this issue?

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid gray;height:490px;margin-top:20px;">
<div id="inner-container" style="background:gray;margin:5px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <p style="margin:5px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <p style="margin:5px;">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't specify inline margins and paddings with spanX classes, as these in override boostrap's own padding/margin settings (this is why the 2nd div goes on the next line. 
I suggest that you create what you need without using spanX definitions for inner divs. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/KGMEF/1/

Comment: I took a look at your sample code - the two divs break apart.  I'm looking for one solid container to hold them both.  I posted a picture in the op so you can see.

Comment: I put a margin around them, that's why. I updated the fiddle, have a look:http://jsfiddle.net/periklis/KGMEF/2/

Comment: Thank you, that looks good.  I even marked this as the answer prior to your update because I understood where you were going.